# Laravel 5.3 validate select input and store in database

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, field, laravel-5.3

I have a registration form and i added 3 select input for date of birth user.

Here the HTML code.

http://hastebin.com/unoxogipuj.vbs

In my RegisterController.php I've added following rules for validation.

```
'day'       => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31',
'month'     => 'required|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12',
'year'      => 'required|in:2003,2002,2001,2000,1999,1998,1997,1996,1995,1994,1993,1992',
```

Again in my RegisterController.php for user creation i added field for store the date in my database

```
'dob'      => $data['day' . 'month' . 'year']
```

In the User Model I've added in protected fillable my field but this don't work.

Comment: Extract that ugly validation rule to its own class (method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **between:min,max** here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-between

Like:

```
'day'   => 'required|between:1,31',
'month' => 'required|between:1,12',
'year'  => 'required|between:2003,1992'
```

And can you please show more controller and model code?